# Заполнить скрытое поле

Tags: javascript

Есть форма:

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="numb1" id="numb1" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="numb2" id="numb2" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="numb3" id="numb3" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="numb4" id="numb4" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="numb5" id="numb5" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="numb6" id="numb6" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Нужно при клике по ссылке заполнить ее.
Ссылки такого вида:

```
<a href="javascript:l_image1 ('/images/r/1.jpg')" class=""><img src="/images/1.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a>
```

Пробовал делать так:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function l_image1 (a) {
 document.numb1.src=a;
 document.numb1.value=a;
 document.getElementsById("numb1").value =a;
}
</script>
```

Но ничего не получается...

---

Есть 6 блоков с ссылками, в каждом блоке по 10 ссылок с изображениями чисел от 0 до 9. Пользователь выбирает в каждом блоке по одному числу (которое загружается в блок справа)

[image]

И значение выбранного числа (или адрес изображения это уже неважно...) должно записаться в скрытую форму, чтобы при клике по кнопке "Отправить", я получил массив из 6 выбранных пользователем значений.

Comment: getElementById, а не getElementsById (буква s лишняя). На странице может быть только один уникальный id. Никаких Elements By Id

Comment: Все равно форма отправляется порожней

Comment: объясните суть того, что вы хотите сделать (какие данные, куда отправлять), возможно форма тут и не нужна, с учётом того, что вы отправляете при нажатии на картинку

Comment: @MasterAlex дополнил вопрос.

Comment: Замените hidden на text и посмотрите, пишет оно у вас что-то в эти поля при нажатии кнопки или нет

Comment: @arashvg, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Используя библиотеку JQuery, написал динамичный вариант кода.

http://jsfiddle.net/9cv180aL/1/

Пару строк закомментировал, так как не указано их происхождение. Если дадите больше кода (включая эти строки), то смогу дописать.